# Python script cant send emails, what could be wrong?

Tags: python

```
fileOfEmails='emails.txt'
fileOfsent='sent.txt'
username=""
password=""


html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  hi
  </body>
</html>
"""


with open(fileOfEmails,'r') as fl:
    content=fl.readlines()

content=[x.strip() for x in content]

with open(fileOfsent,'r') as fl:
    sent=fl.readlines()

sent=[x.strip() for x in sent]

import smtplib
try:

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    print('Smptp established')
except Exception:

    print('SMTP not ServerProblem')


# log in to the server
try:
    server.login(username ,password)
    print('Login successful')
except Exception:
    print('Login ERORr')

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

me = username

i=0
aux='random'
for email in content:
    you=aux+str(i)
    i+=1
    if email not in sent:
        try:
            # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
            msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            msg['mark'] = "Subject"
            msg['test@gmail.com'] = you
            msg['To'] = email


            part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
            msg.attach(part)

            server.sendmail(you, email, msg.as_string())
            server.quit()
            sent.append(email)
            print('Email sent to : ',email)

        except Exception:
            print('Not sent to: ',email)
            continue

with open(fileOfsent, 'w') as f:
    for item in sent:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

After compiling this code, here's my log.

```
Smptp established
Login successful
Not sent to:
```

what could be wrong?
Anyone with idea?

I dont think its a server issue because i have tested gmail smtp too
I have been debugging and still havent found a solution.
Please help
I want it to be able to send emails..
Can someone test this code and give me feedback if it works.
if it doesn't, any possible solution is accepted.
Thanks

Comment: Your first problem is that you have `except Exception`, which masks everything, including syntax errors.  Never do that, especially if you're not going to re-raise the exception after handling it. Get rid of the try/except block, see why it's actually failing, and update your question if the answer doesn't become obvious.

Comment: @larsks I agree with the sentiment that one should not use `except Exception`, but the statement that it will mask a syntax error is incorrect. You are thinking of `BaseException`, which catches everything that `Exception` does as well as `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

Change code to one below and you will get answer in error message:

```
 except Exception as e:
            print('Not sent to: %s because %s' % (email, e))
```

Comment: Not sent to:  because (504, b'5.5.2 <random0>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address', 'random0')

Comment: `email` is an empty string.

Comment: How can i fix that?

Comment: Do you have a blank line at the end of `sent.txt`?